# During training, how to get value of a tensor defined during building time?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

From [this tutorial](https://keras.io/guides/writing_a_training_loop_from_scratch/), one sees that the *loss_value* variable given as param to *tape.gradient()* can have a value like so:

```
tf.Tensor(0.36069894, shape=(), dtype=float32)
```

I am constructing something similar (code is very long and complex, not possible to put it here), but the loss element I access to is computed during building time (so, before the training loop), in this fashion:

```
x = Input(shape=(2,*input_shape))
z = SomeLayer(x)
y = SomeOtherLayer(z)
total_loss = TensorOperations(z)
net = Model(x,y)
```

Where `TensorOperations` can be different operations such as `K.mean`, `K.abs` etc.

But when I print out this total_loss variable during training:

```
with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    net(input_data)
    print(total_loss)
```

I get something like:

```
Tensor("truediv_8:0", shape=(?,), dtype=float32)
```

My question is: how do I get a tensor with an actual value (like the first tensor) ?

[EDIT] the "real" code I am referring to is much more complex, [here is the total_loss variable](https://github.com/guicho271828/latplan/blob/v5.0.0/latplan/model.py#L1511) and [here is the net = Model()](https://github.com/guicho271828/latplan/blob/v5.0.0/latplan/model.py#L1537)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest is probably to include your loss layer as an output of your model:

```
net = Model(x,[y, total_loss])
```

And then, during the training loop:

```
with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    y_pred, loss_value = net(input_data)
    print(loss_value)
```

However, I would advise to try to decouple the loss from the model declaration, it's just more flexible.

Comment: thanks, it's getting close to a solution, the only thing is that total_loss is not a "loss layer", but maybe I can turn it into a layer of the model ? (I got "ValueError: Output tensors to a Model must be the output of a Keras `Layer` (thus holding past layer metadata). Found: Tensor("truediv_8:0", shape=(?,), dtype=float32)
"